# Removing duplicates based on two columns in R

Tags: r

Suppose my data is as follows,

```
X    Y
26  14
26  14
26  15
26  15
27  15
27  15
28  16
28  16
```

I want to remove the rows of duplicates. I am able to remove the duplicate rows based on one column by this command,

```
dat[c(T, diff(dat$X) != 0), ] or dat[c(T, diff(dat$Y) != 0), ]
```

But I want to remove the duplicates only when both the columns have the same previous value. I can't use unique here because the same data would occur later on. I want to check the previous value and calculate it

My sample output is,

```
x   y
26  14
26  15
27  15
28  16
```

How can we do this in R?

Thanks

Ijaz

Comment: Perhaps `dat[Reduce("|",lapply(dat, function(x) c(T, diff(x)!=0))),]`

Comment: There already is a `duplicated` method for dataframes. `dat[!duplicated(dat),]`

Comment: can you try the `Reduce` option.  You mentioned about the other methods are not working.  It may be better to produce an example that does not work with the methods posted.

Comment: @BondedDust This works for all the columns right? I have 7 columns. But I want to remove duplicates using only two columns.

Comment: You've chosen a bad example, IIUC.

Comment: @Observer You can subset the columns to check the duplicates `!duplicated(dat[1:2])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table v1.9.5` - installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
df[!duplicated(rleidv(df, cols = c("X", "Y"))), ]
```

---

`rleidv()` is best understood with examples:

```
rleidv(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4
```

A unique index is generated for each consecutive run of values.

And the same can be accomplished on a `list()` or `data.frame()` or `data.table()` on a specific set of columns as well. For example:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,2,1), b = c(2,3,4,4,2))
rleidv(df) # computes on both columns 'a,b'
# [1] 1 2 3 3 4
rleidv(df, cols = "a") # only looks at 'a'
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3
```

The rest should be fairly obvious. We just check for `duplicated()` values, and return the non-duplicated ones.

Answer (score 0):

using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
z %>% filter(X != lag(X) | Y != lag(Y) | row_number() == 1)
```

We need to include the `row_number()==1` or we lose the first row