# Remove duplicates based on a specific criteria

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataset with programme participants, where I would like to remove clients who participated in two (or more) different programmes. I tried to work around this task by selecting clients with distinct IDs, and clients who participated more than once in the same programme, and then hoping to join these two subsets, but I keep failing. Here is my attempt on a small sample:

```
Client.ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
Program = c("P1", "P2", "P2", "P1", "P2")
From = as.Date(c("2016-10-01", "2016-01-25", "2016-07-01", "2016-04-06", "2016-05-01")) 
To = as.Date(c("2017-03-31", "2016-06-30", "2016-11-27", "2016-06-03", "2016-06-02")) 
df = tibble(Client.ID, Program, From, To)

df
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Client.ID Program       From         To
      <dbl>   <chr>     <date>     <date>
1         1      P1 2016-10-01 2017-03-31
2         2      P2 2016-01-25 2016-06-30
3         2      P2 2016-07-01 2016-11-27
4         3      P1 2016-04-06 2016-06-03
5         3      P2 2016-05-01 2016-06-02


distinct(df, Client.ID, .keep_all = TRUE) #this selects distinct cases nicely
df[duplicated(df$Client.ID) & !duplicated(df$Program),] #but this does not work
```

I tried to look at other questions on the forum, but I only found ones, eg., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711917/removing-duplicates-based-on-two-columns-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742446/duplicates-in-multiple-columns), that deal with duplicates based on two variables. I want to do something else: to remove cases that are duplicates in the first variable, but have *different* values in the second variable. Clients who participated in the same programme multiple times, should stay in the dataset.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `library(dplyr)`:

```
df %>% group_by(Client.ID) %>%
    filter(length(unique(Program)) < 2 )
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand it, but I got it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R version:

```
df[!duplicated(unique(df[, 1:2])[, 1]), ]
```

In words, find the unique pairs and remove duplicates of "Client.ID".

Comment: This one does not seem to work because it retains client 3 in the data frame.